# Rubik Black not working properly or not loading

Tags: css, fonts

I have downloaded the Rubik Font from https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/rubik and i get the zip file and after extracting i get 7-8 Rubik ttf files. 
Some of the file names are Rubik-Black, Rubik-Medium, etc.

I have tried something like this in css but its not working :-

```
body {
    font-family: Rubik-Bold !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    color: #7a8282;
    }
```

Now, I don't know how to install it in my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400,500,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` before the `</head>` . Then use like this:

```
font-family: 'Rubik';
```

for bold:

```
font-family: 'Rubik';
font-weight: 700;
```

for italic:

```
font-family: 'Rubik';
font-style: italic;
```